# Convert bool to QString

Tags: c++, qt

I want convert bool to QString.

Whats the most efficient way to do it?, This is my code but sure that there is other way better.

```
bool test = true;
test ? "1" : "0";
```

Thanks.

Comment: No better way that I know of.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `QString(test ? "1" : "0")`?

Comment: Yes larsmans sorry my copy/paste not work fine sorry

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the static `QString::number` method - the bool will be implicitly cast to int to match the integer form of the static factory method, which returns a `QString` containing `0` or `1`.

```
bool test = true;
QString s = QString::number(test);
```

Answer (score 24):

Use QVariant!

From bool to QString:

```
   bool bInput = false;
   QString s = QVariant(bInput).toString();
```

From QString to bool:

```
  QString s = "true";
  bool bInUse = QVariant(s).toBool();
```

Answer (score 11):

qDebug() displays a bool variable as "true" or "false". If you want to get such a string you can change your code a little bit:

```
bool test = true;
QString boolText = test ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool test = true;
QString s = QVariant(test).toString();
```

This results in "true" or "false", and is internationalized in the Qt translation in qtbase_xx.qm.